# Converting a raster layer into a spatstat object

Tags: r, spatial

I'm new to spatial analysis in R and need help. Could any one tell me how I can convert a rasterLayer into a spatstat object in R.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10, vals=1:100)
```

Solution

```
library(maptools)
m <- as.im.RasterLayer(r)
m
#integer-valued pixel image
#10 x 10 pixel array (ny, nx)
#enclosing rectangle: [-180, 180] x [-90, 90] units
```